# What is the music that plays in episode 21 of Shippuden?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the name of the piece that plays in [episode 21 (Shippuden)](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden/episode-21-sasoris-real-face-509810) from 02:30-02:53?

I have listened to many Naruto soundtracks, but still I still haven't able to find this one...  it seems to be played in many episodes.

Comment: Have you tried something like Shazam? It sometimes works for asian music.

Answer (score 5):

This is [Track 21 - Kouchaku ( Stalemate )](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Yo5SoZcAUg) from the [Naruto Shippūden: Original Soundtrack (2007)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Music).